# iPhone How To Save View States

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have been developing iphone applications for around 3months now and theres a few things that stump me and i don't really have an idea how to work round them.

I have a navigation controller controlling the views in my application however every screen that is loaded, used then pushed back loses all the information as it seems to be reinstantiated... I believe this is a possible memory management issue?

But how to i create an app that navigates and retains all information in its views until the application is closed.

Thanks :)

Comment: isn't the view controller released when poped off the stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible you didn't keep a reference to the view controller, the issue is for `UIVIewController` not to be released.

Make the view controller an ivar you will instanciate only one time when you push it on stack.

```
// in .h
MyViewController *mVC;

// in .m
// maybe when the user selects a row in a tableview
if(mVC == nil) {
    // first time use, alloc/init
    mVC = [[MyViewController ....];
}
// then push on the stack
[self.navigationController ....];
```

Of course don't forget to release it later.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? i'm currently trying to do it with a uitextfield. push on the viewcontroller, type in text in the uitextfield, pop off. then pop back to see if the text is still there. Is the only way to save the data that i entered in the textfield to use nsuserdefaults or something?

Comment: @MrPink - the state of your controls isn't saved, because the `UIViewController` gets released. Was the issue to save state to filesystem ? I didn't understood like that.

Comment: @MrPink - If you want to preserve the state when you push/pop/push again, the `UIViewController` must not get released, and to do that, just register it as an ivar in your class, when you need to push it, check if it is `nil` (first push) and alloc/init it. Then, when you will pop it off the stack, it won't get relesead, unless you explicitly ask for that. And when you will push it again, unless you do an update in `viewDidAppear:`, the state of your controls will remain the same

Comment: I'm still trying to get it too work. I'll keep fiddling with all the info you have given me and let you know :)

Comment: @MrPink - the unique difference is that the VC is made an ivar of your custom class, instead of being declared/alloc/init when you need to push it

Comment: OK i have my uitextfield in my secondview. I push on the viewcontroller, type something in the textfield then go back to my firstview. pushing then back to the secondview the uitextfield is empty...

Comment: @MrPink - is the pushed VC an ivar ? don't you instanciate it each time you push it ? this can appear for various reasons, can your code be viewed anywhere ?

Comment: @MrPink - I'll make a test project to show you and put a link to download it in my next comment

Comment: hi thanks very much, i've got it to work. I can see what your code was trying to do. Check if the object had been allocated. If it had then use it. if not allocate another. This way I'm always using the same viewcontroller. Just got to know when is best to deallocate it now. Because as objects allocate further objects they will on need to be released in succession? Sorry if these are noob questions... I think i may of just got my head around memory allocation on the iphone.

Comment: @MrPink - great ! you should release in dealloc.

Comment: in the dealloc where the object is pushed from yes? just as i thought. thanks for your time and your help :)

Comment: @user756245, hello. i have been using this method without many hiccups so thanks very much. but i have a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

```
MyViewController *myViewController=[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
[myViewController release];
```

You will probably have something like this... Instead, make your myViewController a class's property so you have a reference to it. And drop the `[myViewController release];` statement.

Comment: wrong answer. plz refer the above answer. works like a magic.

Comment: @AbdulYasin, for you might be (in your specific case). If you look at the op question, you will see it's too vague, to give an objective answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your app is receiving a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

In such cases, when the super class is called, the framework does memory cleaning by unloading all the views that are not currently displayed. This could explain the behavior you are seeing.

To check it further, override `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in one of your view controllers or `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` in your app delegate, and put a breakpoint in it. Don't forget to call `[super...]` appropriately, otherwise pretty soon your app will be killed. What you should see in this way is that the views do not disappear before hitting the breakpoint, and do disappear after that.

If the hypothesis is correct, you should find a way to save the state of your view in `viewDidUnload` and restore it in `viewDidLoad`. Look also at [didReceiveMemoryWarning](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save data in `NSUserDefaults` it its small or use `plist` or it its too small like 5-10 objects save in in some variable in `appDelegate`, and if its too large use `sqlite` and for saving something like images of files like xml use `Document directory`

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationController works like a stack: you push and pop UIViewControllers on it. That means when a UIViewController get popped, it will have its retain count decremented by 1, and if no other object holds a reference to it, it will be deallocated. You can avoid the UIViewControllers getting dealloced by keeping a reference to them yourself by calling -retain on the objects, for instance in your appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to save the states of the UIControls in the view.

So whenever u r loading a view, set the values to the controls so that it looks like it resume from the place where we left.

Comment: This is what i have been doing. But i thought there was an easier way, by saving or keeping the entire view in memory. Each time a page is pushed and popped it will have to access what i have saved in nsuserdefaults?