# iPhone Save App View State

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using a UINavigationController on iPhone 5

How can I save the state of a view before the user moves to the next? So that when the user clicks 'Back', their changes are not lost?

My question is similar to this one:
[iPhone How To Save View States](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827787/iphone-how-to-save-view-states)

But I am using storyboards & segue.. so there is no stack?

My code to move from 1 view to the next is:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueAnnotationDetail" sender:self];
```

Then I have `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    // save view state here?

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueAnnotationDetail"])
    {
        AnnotationDetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        [vc setMyAnnotationView:selectedAnnotation];
    }
}
```

Ideally I put some code in `//save view state here` to save the state of the view?

Comment: While pushing using the UINavigationController the parent class state will remain unaffected ..how have u implemented the push?

Comment: I have this code in another method:
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueAnnotationDetail" sender:self];`

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question myself

There was a bug in my code - it was because of that